# Question on CSS width:100%

Tags: css, html, margin

I want to create a flexible grid layout (i.e. no pixel value to be used anywhere)
Now here is my question;
For the outer container, generally I use

```
#container{width:1024px;margin:0 auto}
```

This is to center align the entire page. Now when I convert the same to a % based CSS i.e.

```
#container{width:100%;margin:0 auto}
```

In this case, the page does not center align. How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you seem to be needing something to stop the container from widening infinitely, but still have it expand flexibly when the viewport is narrow. If this is the case, you can apply a `max-width` on it to tell it when to stop expanding:

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

In this case, your container will be flexible and take up all available width if the viewport is less than 1024 pixels wide, but won't go beyond 1024 pixels (and will be center-aligned) if the window grows wider.

Answer (score 3):

Page can't align centrally because it uses full browser width.
try for example: "width:80%", and you'll see what i am talking about;

Comment: Actually, the page **is** center aligned but you can't tell because it taking the full page width.

Comment: I am not sure if width:80% is truely universal solution (meaning cross-browser) and I am not very comfortable with it...Is there any other way to fix this ?

Comment: Я з Полтави, а ти? Тут вгорі є лінк chat, можемо трохи поспілкуватися, якщо вийде. Never did it before :)

Comment: @testndtv Container is your main wrapper. Leave it with width 100% (or even delete width, the result will be the same. And place a new div inside of the container width fixed width or width < 100%). I think it'll help.

Comment: Був 2 роки назад, гарне місто. Ок, я надумаєш, свисти. Заразом спробуємо отримати по бейджику Talkative :)

Answer (score 2):

True, how can you expect something to be center aligned when it fills up the entire width.

Answer (score 2):

You container **does** center align. Width of 100% means that the container occupies all width of parent container (let's assume screen), thus **space for margins is 0**.
Generally such problems are easily tracked with applying border to containers.

You can fix this issue by centering elements **inside** your container with `text-align: center;`

Comment: text-align is something like horizontal-align (which does not exist) and works for all **inline** elements.

Comment: (accidentally submitted. Continuation)
Block level elements are:
 * by default 100% width of parent element
 * non-alignable
 * positionable (width: 80%; position: relative; left: 10%; /* or margin: auto */)

Hope that helps